# Touchpad two-finger scrolling and two-finger tap for right click stop working

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad

I am using Kubuntu 22.04 on an LG Gram 17" laptop using kernel 5.15.0-47-generic (64 bit).
Ii is running KDE Plasma verson 5.24.6 and using the X11 graphics platform

Since upgrading to Kubuntu 22.04 I find that the Touchpad two-finger scrolling and two-finger tap for right click functions stop working after a few minutes of use.  When this happens, the mouse acceleration also becomes noticeably increased. There is no apparent pattern to the failures as far as workflow is concerned.

If I reboot, the problem goes away for a few minutes and then re-appears.

I have reloaded the operating system by firstly, installing kubuntu 20.04 from a live usb, then performing a full upgrade followed by a do-release-upgrade.
The upgrade functioned properly for a few hours of use, sufficiently long enough for me to think I had solved the problem, then it reappeared!.

I notice that if the laptop lid is closed and re-opened, the touchpad works normally for a few minutes then fails again.
I have read other reports of this problem but have not been able to resolve the issue.
I have not noticed the problem using kubuntu 20.04

How do I identify the touchpad driver that is in use?
Do you think it may be a kernel problem - i.e would rolling back the kernel solve this?
Are there any other drivers available for this distribution?

My fallback position is to reload kubuntu 20.04 and run with that for the foreseeable future.

### Update: 12 Oct 2022

After re-installing kubuntu 20.04 and using it daily for a month, the unthinkable has happened.  The touchpad no longer scrolls - the pointer speed side-effect is different but I had to reboot anyway to get touchpad two-finger scroll back.  This laptop came installed with windows 11 (which I have nuked) - so I would like to hear from other LG Gram PC users out there. Woe is me.